# Multiple child components getting same prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two self-defined class components, from which I create two instances like:

```
<PersonAddModal details={details} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} addFather={false}/>
```

So the `addFather` property is different, the rest is the same.

The `PersonAddModal` looks as follows. (The Add father/Add mother text is displayed correctly though, depending on the val of addFather)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'react-responsive-modal';


class PersonAddModal extends React.Component 
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }



    handleSubmit(event)
    {
    //...
    }
    
    getParentTypeString()
    {
        return this.props.addFather ? "father" : "mother";
    }

    render() {
        return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.setOpen(true)}>{this.props.addFather ? <div>Add father</div>:<div>Add mother</div>}</button>
                                    <Modal open={this.props.open} onClose={() => this.props.setOpen(false)}>
                                        <h1>Add a {this.getParentTypeString()} of {this.props.details.firstName}</h1>
                                        <form onSubmit={(event) => {this.handleSubmit(event)}}>
                                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" required/>
                                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" required/>
                                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </Modal>
    </div>
        )};
}

export default PersonAddModal;
```

I really don't understand why (apparently) the val of addFather of the latest added component seems also to be used for the first component. Aren't they supposed to be independant from each other? Help is graetly appreciated!

Edit:
They;re being used as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import 'react-responsive-modal/styles.css';
import { Modal } from 'react-responsive-modal';
import PersonLink from './PersonLink'
import PersonAddModal from './PersonAddModal'

const PersonDetails = ({ match }) => {



    const [details, setDetails] = React.useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://localhost:44332/api/person/${match.params.id}/details`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => { setDetails(data); setIsLoading(false); });


    }, [match.params.id])

    return (
        <>
            {
                (isLoading || details.id == null) ? <h1>Loading..</h1>
                    :
                    <>
                        <h1>Person Details of {details.firstName} {details.lastName}</h1>
                        <h2>Parents </h2>
                        {
                            details.father != null && details.father != 0 ?
                            <PersonLink id={details.father  } />
                                :
                                <>
                                    <PersonAddModal details={details} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} addFather={true}/>
                                </>
                        }
                        {
                            details.mother != null && details.mother != 0 ?
                                <PersonLink id={details.mother} />
                                :
                                <PersonAddModal details={details} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} addFather={false}/>
                        }
                        {details.spouse != 0 ?
                            <>
                                <h2>Spouse</h2>
                                <PersonLink id={details.spouse}/>
                            </>
                            : <></>}
                        <h2>Siblings</h2>
                        {
                            details.siblings.map((sibling) => (<PersonLink id={sibling} />))
                        }
                        <h2>Children</h2>
                        {
                            details.children.map((child) => (<PersonLink id={child} />))
                        }
                    </>
            }



        </>
    );
};


export default PersonDetails;
```

Comment: Can you show us how the components are being used? That seems to be the more likely source of the bug.

Comment: Here, the complete code of how they're being used: (added in the edit above)

Comment: Try giving each `PersonLInk` a unique key. Like `<PersonLink key="father" id={details.father  } />`.

Comment: Hi @BrianThompson, tried that but still doesnt make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer:

As you could see, I was creating two Modals, and my issue was that both were displaying the same. Turns out that because I was giving them both the same state (open/setOpen), no matter on which I clicked, always the same was opening.

Comment: You are correct. I've even [answered this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581998/react-modal-always-take-the-last-element-of-map-function/59582367#59582367) before, and I still didn't catch it!